# MonoTouch: Get latitude and longitude values crashes

Tags: xamarin.ios, cllocationmanager, latitude-longitude

In my app i want to get the latitude and longitude values. I have below code. It crashes very first time the function get called. App asks the user permission to use current location and app crashes throwing null reference exception where i am assigning latitude value to a string

```
string getLocation()
{
   string latlong = "|";

   CLLocationManager locationManager = new CLLocationManager();

   locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();

   //var locationVar = locationManager.Location.Coordinate;

   string lat = locationManager.Location.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
   string lon = locationManager.Location.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
   latlong = lat + "|" + lon;


   return latlong;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the location from locationManager until it has retrieved a location. You need to assign an event handler that will be called when the location is found.

The [CoreLocation sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/CoreLocation/MainScreen/MainViewController.cs) from Xamarin includes a complete example of how to do this

```
// handle the updated location method and update the UI
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (6, 0)) {
  iPhoneLocationManager.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) => {
    UpdateLocation (mainScreen, e.Locations [e.Locations.Length - 1]);
  };
} else {
  // this won't be called on iOS 6 (deprecated)
  iPhoneLocationManager.UpdatedLocation += (object sender, CLLocationUpdatedEventArgs e) => {
    UpdateLocation (mainScreen, e.NewLocation);
  };
}
```

Comment: Just a small issue the UpdateLocation function gets called multiple times. Is that how it works. In my app i dont want to call it multiple times.

Comment: If your phone is moving, the GPS will update as the location changes.  Call StopUpdatingLocation() when you want to stop getting updates.

Comment: The very first time i call the UpdateLocation it is getting called multiple times. In my code, when i get the lat, long values i am stoping the update(StopUpdatingLocation) but still it ends up giving me lat/long values multiple times.

Comment: The GPS might be returning values faster than you're responding to them.  If you only want the first value, just use a bool to track whether or not you've gotten the first update.  After it is set, ignore any future updates, and also call StopUpdatingLocation()